# UISearchViewController hides tabbar during presentation

Tags: ios, uisearchcontroller

I use `UISearchViewController` to control my app's search stuff. I saw there's a property called `hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation` for handling the navigationBar's visibility, but what I wanna do is to hide tabbar during presentation, I can't find any properties to do this.

Any work-around?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right that there's no property for explicitly showing & hiding the tab bar, but it's easy enough to implement yourself:

1. Make your view controller (not the `UISearchController`) implement `UISearchControllerDelegate`.
2. Assign your view controller to the search controller's `delegate` property.
3. Implement `willPresentSearchController()` (or `didPresentSearchController()`) and `presentSearchController()` to hide your tab bar. (The former is called when the search bar is automatically shown; the latter is called when you show it manually.)
4. Implement `willDismissSearchController()` (or `didDismissSearchController`) to show it again.

Note that if your implementations simply toggle the search bar's `hidden` property, then the bar won't animate in and out; you'll have to do your own animation.

It may be a good idea for your implementations to check the value of `hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation` so that your tab bar is shown and hidden only when the navigation bar is.